# Young adult post-apocalyptic novel with male lead who calls mannequins white statues

Tags: story-identification

I don't have much information to go on. Someone I know read this book in 2010, and we're trying to figure out what it was.

Here's what we know remember:

There is some **alien influence** involved, but it is not necessarily a direct conflict with them.

The lead protagonist is a **male**. At one point he enters a **shopping mall** and sees **mannequins** but he calls them **white statues**

There is possibly a **sickness** element too.

This was read in school in **2010**

Sorry, I know this is REALLY not a lot to go on. But would appreciate an attempt :D

Comment: This makes me think of one of the YA Charlie Higsons "Enemy" series.  - but unfortunately I've not read all of them so I can't pin down which book in particular you're seeking. Hope this helps as a pointer for somebody.